# Is mass relative?

Tags: special-relativity, mass, inertial-frames, speed

Since time is relative to the observer's velocity, does that mean that velocities are also relative, since the same distance is covered in a different time, depending on your reference frame?  If velocities are relative, does that mean that kinetic energy is also relative via $E_{kinetic} = \frac{1}{2} mv^2$?  And if kinetic energy is relative, does that mean that mass is relative, via $E = mc^2$ ?

Comment: Closely related/possible duplicate: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/133376/50583

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is there a controversy on whether mass increases with speed?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/133376/)

Comment: Note: the approximation $E_\text{kinetic} \equiv (\gamma-1)mc^2 \approx \frac12 mv^2$ is only valid in the nonrelativistic limit $v\ll c$.